# Python property has created two variables

Tags: python, properties

I have two private variables (properties) and I gave them getters and setters and now it has created two variables for each (I only want one, and I want it to be private):

```
_indoor_location_cards
indoor_location_cards
_outdoor_location_cards
outdoor_location_cards
```

I found this out in the debugger.

Here is my code:

```
the_game = None
class Game(object):
    """Template for the Zimp game."""
    _indoor_location_cards = []
    _outdoor_location_cards = []
    game_dev_cards = []
    the_user = None
    items = []
    the_time = None
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    #getter and setter for the private indoor card list
    def indoor_location_cards():
        doc = """The priavte list for indoor location cards
              of the game. Has a getter, setter, & deleter"""
        def fget(self):
            return self._indoor_location_cards
        def fset(self, value):
            self._indoor_location_cards = value
        def fdel(self):
            del self._indoor_location_cards[0:len(self._indoor_location_cards)]
        return locals()  # credit: David Niergarth
    indoor_location_cards = property(**indoor_location_cards())

    #getter and setter for the private outdoor card list
    def outdoor_location_cards():
        doc = """The priavte list for outdoor location cards
              of the game. Has a getter, setter, & deleter"""
        def fget(self):
            return self._outdoor_location_cards
        def fset(self, value):
            self._outdoor_location_cards = value
        def fdel(self):
            del self._outdoor_location_cards[0:len(self._outdoor_location_cards)]
        return locals()  # credit: David Niergarth
    outdoor_location_cards = property(**outdoor_location_cards())

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the_game is a module scope variable holding an instance of Game.

I only use the code to set the_games properties like this:

```
    model.zimp.the_game = model.zimp.Game()
        model.zimp.the_game.the_time = datetime.time(9, 0)
        # Add the indoor cards to the indoor cards list.
        model.zimp.the_game._indoor_location_cards.append(card1)
        model.zimp.the_game._indoor_location_cards.append(card2)
        model.zimp.the_game._indoor_location_cards.append(card3)
model.zimp.the_game._outdoor_location_cards.append(card9)
        model.zimp.the_game._outdoor_location_cards.append(card10)
        model.zimp.the_game._outdoor_location_cards.append(card11)
```

Comment: If you make it a single variable then what will you return from `fget` and what you'll set in `fset`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary All I know is getters and setters give me access to the property, beyond that, I'm quite new to this.. Is it meant to make two variables? If so, I didn't know that, and that is fine.

Comment: See the examples used in [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), so you're doing it right. And also read: [We are all consenting adults here.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html) :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thank you! The official python docs document on properties may take me a couple of reads to sink in properly :P I understand how to use it, maybe just not everything about what really happens. Which will do for now :-)